# Why do I receive an unexpected result when result is calculated in switch statement?

Tags: c, algorithm

Firstly, I wanted to do simple calculator program.
I entered equation as `2-3*4`. Also, this code is arranged according to be priority sequence among operators.
If I mention about unexpected result, at `result=(usertxt[i] * usertxt[i + 2]); printf("%d\n", result); usertext[i]=3, usertext[4]` according to equation then I got `2652` from `result` at this code. When I expect `12` from `result`, how can I correct this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int i;

int main() {
    char a[100] = { 0, }, usertxt[100] = { 0, };
    a[99] = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int myoperator = 0;
    int num;
    printf("Please, enter your calculation\n");
    gets_s(a,sizeof(a));
    printf("You entered: %s\n", a);
    num = strlen(a);
    printf("Number of characters: %d\n", num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        usertxt[i + 1] = a[i];
        printf("%c", usertxt[i + 1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (usertxt[i + 1] == '*' || usertxt[i + 1] == '/') {
            myoperator = usertxt[i + 1];
        }
        {
            switch (myoperator) {
              case '*':
                printf("Multiplication operation\n");
                printf("%c%c", usertxt[i], usertxt[i + 2]);
                result = 0;
                result = (usertxt[i] * usertxt[i + 2]);
                printf("%d\n", result);
                break;
              case '/':
                printf("Division operation\n");
                result = usertxt[i] / usertxt[i + 2];
                printf("Result=%d\n", result);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (usertxt[i + 1] == '+' || usertxt[i + 1] == '-') {
            myoperator = usertxt[i + 1];
        }
        {
            switch (myoperator) {
              case '+':
                printf("Addition operation\n");
                result = usertxt[i] + usertxt[i + 2];
                printf("Result=%d\n", result);
                break;
              case '-':
                printf("Subtraction operation\n");
                result = usertxt[i] - usertxt[i + 2];
                printf("Result=%d\n", result);
                break;
              default:
                printf("Please, try again.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this compile? `gets_s(a)` is missing the `sizeInCharacters` argument. Also please don't use non-portable and unreadable hard-coding like `case 42:` but `case '*':` .

Comment: 'how can I correct this issue?' ........have you considered debugging your app?

Comment: Of course. Martin James

Comment: Weather Vane, I can compile it but I encountered unexpected result as I said. Code is being gotten more understable condition. Could you look at again?

Comment: `if (usertxt[i + 1] > 41) {` <<-- has never been assigned a value.

Comment: Wildplasser, indeed, it is true. Changes are renewed.

Comment: You need to extract numbers from the text entered. The characters in the text `"3*4"` have the ASCII values `51` and `52` and `51 * 52` is `2652`.

Comment: Ok Weather Vane, could you give more specific information to be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems in your implementation:

- you should first convert the string into an array of values and a separate array of operators. Digits in the string are characters: their numeric value is obtained by subtracting the code for `'0'` from the `char` value.
- then you would handle operators in several passes, one for each precedence level, assuming left to right associativity. You do this but when you handle an operator, you should shift all values and operators to its right to remove the second argument from the array.
- the final value is at index 0 of the `int` array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char expr[100];
    int values[50];
    char operators[50];
    char *p;
    int i, j, n, result;

    printf("Please, enter your calculation\n");
    if (!fgets(expr, sizeof expr, stdin)) {
        printf("Missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // analyse the expression
    for (p = expr, n = 0;;) {
        if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
            //values[n] = strtol(p, 0, &p);
            values[n] = *p - '0';
            p++;
        } else {
            printf("Missing operand\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (*p == '\n') {
            // strip the trailing newline
            *p = '\0';
        }
        if (*p == '\0') {
            // end of the expression
            // there are n operators and n+1 operands
            break;
        }
        if (!strchr("+-*/", *p)) {
            printf("Invalid operator: %c\n", *p);
            return 1;
        }
        operators[n] = *p;
        p++;
        n++;
    }
    printf("You entered: %s\n", expr);
    /* handle multiplicative operators */
    for (i = 0; i < n;) {
        switch (operators[i]) {
          case '*':
            printf("Multiplication operation\n");
            result = values[i] * values[i + 1];
            break;
          case '/':
            printf("Division operation\n");
            result = values[i] / values[i + 1];
            break;
          case '%':
            printf("Modulo operation\n");
            result = values[i] % values[i + 1];
            break;
          default:
            i++;
            continue;  // skip other operators
        }
        printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", values[i], operators[i], values[i + 1], result);
        values[i] = result;
        // shift remaining operators and operands
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            operators[j - 1] = operators[j];
            values[j] = values[j + 1];
        }
        n--;
    }
    /* handle additive operators */
    for (i = 0; i < n;) {
        switch (operators[i]) {
          case '+':
            printf("Addition operation\n");
            result = values[i] + values[i + 1];
            break;
          case '-':
            printf("Subtraction operation\n");
            result = values[i] - values[i + 1];
            break;
          default:
            i++;
            continue;  // skip other operators
        }
        printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", values[i], operators[i], values[i + 1], result);
        values[i] = result;
        // shift remaining operators and operands
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            operators[j - 1] = operators[j];
            values[j] = values[j + 1];
        }
        n--;
    }
    printf("Result: %d\n", values[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
Please, enter your calculation
1+2*4-6/5
You entered: 1+2*4-6/5
Multiplication operation
2 * 4 = 8
Division operation
6 / 5 = 1
Addition operation
1 + 8 = 9
Subtraction operation
9 - 1 = 8
Result: 8
```

Try extending the code along the following ideas:

- generalize to arbitrary integers using `strtol()` as shown in the comment.
- skip whitespace in the analysis loop to accept `1 + 2*6 - 10`.
- handle bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `^`
- implement `double` arithmetics with `strtod()`

This iterative method is OK for simple expressions, but more elaborate parsing (recursive descent, tree conversion, finite state machines) is recommended to support:

- unary operators: `-1`, `-2*3`, `-2*-3`...
- parentheses
- variables
- function calls
- assignments

Answer (score 0):

Note that the character '3' is 51 in ascii, '4' is 52, and that 51 * 54 == 2652.  You're multiplying the ascii values, not the numbers 3 and 4.  You would see that by changing the debug print statement to use `%d` instead of `%c`.

Comment: Could you give more obvious information which lines should be changed about "%d instead of %c"?

Comment: `printf("%c%c", usertxt[i], usertxt[i + 2]);` was the specific one that looked like you put it in for debugging purposes.  Overall, if you want to see what you're working with operators should be printed with `%c`, numeric values with `%d`